# how to type greek latin letters in comment section of R script on the fly

Tags: r, character-encoding, symbols

When I want to write greek/latin letters in a comment section in an R script (not R Markdown), I end up copying and pasting the relevant letters from another source. Is there a way to type these on the fly in a windows operating system?

typical rscript:

```
library(tidyverse)
#comment section
#gamma distribution has two parameters, α and β. Wait time follows Γ(k, λ)
x <- 1:10
```

All references I find are for writing these letters are for putting them in a graph (`expression(beta)`) or in R Markdown (`$\beta$`) which is not what I am after.

I was wondering does anyone know of an `addin` or how to create a `snippet` where you could press `tab` to see a list of all letters and simply click which one you wanted?

thanks

Comment: How you type non-ascii characters would depended on your operating system. It would be the same way you would include those characters in an email. There are some ideas at https://superuser.com/questions/936999/fastest-way-to-type-greek-letters-like-%CE%B1-or-%CE%B2

Comment: You could create RStudio snippets for each of the letters but snippets don't activate in comments. It may be better to make a feature request at the RStudio support site: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: There's a couple of approaches for this with Rstudio addins. It could be a popup box, where you use a keyboard shortcut to bring up a box and click or tab over to the letter to insert. Or you could do something where you type out "alpha", select it, and then use a keyboard shortcut to replace it with the Greek letter. Which kind of interface would be more natural?

Comment: @Brian the first idea sounds great and exactly what I was thinking. The second approach is slightly longer having to type out the word and highlight. Seeing all of them in a popup at once is better. Additionally, if it could give you the choice of inserting a few at a time from the popup, that would be ideal. What do you think? Do you have an addin example with a pop up window? I haven't come across them specifically.

Comment: request added https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/6243

Comment: @user63230 I just checked your Github issue and it looks like that's not a feature they're interested in supporting. I did have a few ideas about how to implement such an Addin, I'll add an answer below with a prototype.